# MYSQL join query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 mysql tables named

1. blog
2. comment

What i am trying to do to retrieve following columns
 `user_name` `comment_desc` from the comment table using blog_id.

Both the tables have blog_id in common.

here below are the screenshots of both sql tables

Comment Table:
[image: comment table]

Blog Table:
[image: blog table]

I tried the query this way.

```sql
SELECT blog.blog_id, comment.user_name, comment.comment_desc 
    FROM 
        blog (b) 
    INNER JOIN 
        comment (c)
        ON b.blog_id = c.blog_id
```

i dont have access to upload the image thats why i uploaded to photobucket.

The PHP Code....

```
<?php

                        $comments_set = blog_comments();
                        var_dump($comments_set);
                        while($comments_all = mysql_fetch_assoc($comments_set)){
                            $name = $comments_all['user_name'];
                            $desc = $comments_all['comment_desc'];
                            echo                    
                            "<ol class=\"commentlist clearfix\">

                                <li class=\"comment even thread-even depth-1\" id=\"li-comment-1\">

                                    <div id=\"comment-1\" class=\"comment-wrap clearfix\">

                                        <div class=\"comment-meta\">

                                            <div class=\"comment-author vcard\">

                                                <span class=\"comment-avatar clearfix\">
                                                <img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=60' class='avatar avatar-60 photo avatar-default' height='60' width='60' /></span>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                        <div class=\"comment-content clearfix\">

                                            <div class=\"comment-author\">$name<span><a href=\"#\" title=\"Permalink to this comment\">January 24, 2013 at 10:46 am</a> &middot; <a class='comment-reply-link' href=\"#\">Reply</a></span></div>

                                            <p>$desc</p>


                                        </div>

                                    </div>


                                </li>



                            </ol>
                            ";
                        }
                            ?>
```

Comment: Why is the query not working?  Do you get an error?

Comment: Actually you can post the output of console output (e.g. `DESC blog`) here.

Comment: @shin, 32 and 34 blog_ids are in both tables.

Comment: i am getting this error......Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\New smartbakhtar\blog-single.php on line 187

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` would be better, because `INNER JOIN` will ignore blogs that don't have comment.

Comment: @AhadMurtaza That appears to be a different issue. Please post the actual code that you are running.

Comment: No, all blogs are visible but the comments that are in the database are not showing.

Comment: @AhadMurtaza That error simply means that your previous query (possible `SELECT`) fails. Check `mysql_error` for MySQL error, not PHP error. And update your error onto your question so others can see too.

Comment: why using bracket before b and c? try: SELECT blog.blog_id, comment.user_name, comment.comment_desc FROM blog b INNER JOIN comment c ON b.blog_id = c.blog_id

Comment: @AhadMurtaza - problem appears to be somewhere in `blog_comments()` function, so please post its code also

Comment: You need to post the actual error you are getting.

Comment: You have to remove parenthesis and do alias wisely...Check out my answer....

Comment: function blog_comments(){
  global $connection;
  $query = "SELECT blog.blog_id, comment.user_name, comment.comment_desc 
     FROM 
      blog b 
     LEFT JOIN 
      comment c
       ON b.blog_id = c.blog_id ";
  $comment = mysql_query($query, $connection);
  return $comment; 
}

Comment: ERROR                                                                              Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\New smartbakhtar\blog-single.php on line 186

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using alias so at the time of `SELECT` statement, specify it through alias name. You need to remove parenthesis around alias name...

```
SELECT b.blog_id, c.user_name, c.comment_desc 
    FROM 
        blog b 
    INNER JOIN 
        comment c
        ON b.blog_id = c.blog_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `user_name` and `desc` from `comment` table with `blog_ig`

Why you need to join these 2 tables then ? you could retrieve information from comment table by blog id

`select * from comments where blog_id='blog_id'`

Comment: The both have two fields common i.e blog_id.so that the a specific comment is for some specific blog.

Comment: Ahad Bhai, in either way you have to mention blog_id, or the lef join can be the good option here, hav u tried it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for Left Join because may be you want to have blogs to be displayed whether they have comments or not.

```
SELECT b.blog_id, c.user_name, c.comment_desc 
    FROM 
        blog as b
    LEFT JOIN 
        comment as c
        ON b.blog_id = c.blog_id
```

Comment: exactly what you are getting in result set?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have incorrectly define the blog_id columns. Please check columns' datatype and sizes.
It will fail when joining tables.
If you can paste error it will be more helpful

Thanks.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\New smartbakhtar\blog-single.php on line 187

Comment: first check if query is working on it own on mysql server. i think you have sql error which will then be printed.

Comment: This php error occurs when null object returns. Error in you sql code. It doesn't return results. Did you run this sql without using the php code? Try this in phpmyadmin. Then you can see mysql errors.

Comment: Run sql query in phpmyadmin, then you can see errors. Did you run sql?

Comment: i checked it using var_dump() whether its returning any values but it returned "false."

Comment: Don't check in php code level. Check in database level by running your sql.

Comment: If you want to check this in php code, you can use mysql_error function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: check for mysql connection in blog_comments() function. 
if (!$connection) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
Or just create database connection again here(mysql_connect) and execute mysql_query command.